# How to trigger Artifactory license check from Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We are running our project builds from a Jenkins pipeline script (Jenkins 2.183, Artifactory Plugin 3.3.1) and uploading the build artifacts to Artifactory. We would now like to trigger the license checks and notification mails from Artifactory.

How can we trigger this check with the current plugin (preferable directly from the pipeline script)?

We also have an older Jenkins server that deploys to the same Artifactory instance. In that server we can trigger the license check as described here:

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/License+Control#LicenseControl-BuildServerConfiguration

The Artifactory server must support the license check functionality as it works from this older build system, but with the new Jenkins server / Artifactory plugin this configuration option doesn't seem to be available and there is no reference to it in the plugin documentation. I can't find any mention of this functionality in the pipeline DSL documentation either.

In the changelog for the Artifactory Plugin is a change from 27.12.2018 that says:

```
Removed deprecated actions and APIs

Removed the following actions/APIs from both UI and code: 
1. Bintray Publish Action.
2. License control.
3. Black Duck.
4. JenkinsXArtifactoryBuilderListener.
```

Unfortunately I can't find any information about why this was deprecated or what is supposed to replace the deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

License check functionality was replaced by Xray.

You can find the documentation for the new pipeline step [here (declarative)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-ScanningBuildswithJFrogXray) or [here (scripted)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-ScanningBuildswithJFrogXray.1).